# Find analytically $x(t)$ $ \dot{x}= x-x^3$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find analytically $x(t)$

$$ \dot{x}= x-x^3$$

---

Asked computer gave out

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}=x-x^3$$
$$\frac{1}{x-x^3}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}=1$$
Integrate both sides with respect to $t$:
$$t=\int \frac{1}{x-x^3}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}\mathrm{d}t$$
$$t=\int \frac{1}{x-x^3}\mathrm{d}x$$
Now we can use partial fraction decomposition:
$$t=\int \frac{A}{x}+\frac{B}{1-x}+\frac{C}{1+x}\mathrm{d}x$$
$$t=A\log(x)-B\log(1-x)+C\log(1+x)+\text{constant}$$
You can find $A$,$B$ and $C$ easily : $A=1$, $B=\frac{1}{2}$, $C=-\frac{1}{2}$, So:
$$t=\log(x)-\frac{1}{2}\log(1-x)-\frac{1}{2}\log(1+x)+\text{constant}$$
$$t=\log\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)+\text{constant}$$

Answer (score 0):

you can write
$$\frac{dx}{x-x^3}=dt$$

Answer (score 0):

First of all notice that we have two trivial solutions $$ x=1 \text {  and  } x=0 $$
In order to solve this  separable differential equation $$\dot{x}= x-x^3$$ we divide both side by $x-x^3$ to get $$ \frac {dx}{x-x^3} =dt $$

Upon integrating both side and using partial fraction we come up with $$ ln(|x|)-(1/2)ln(|1-x^2|)=t+c$$

$$ln(\frac {|x|}{\sqrt {1-x^2}})=t+c $$

$$\frac {x}{\sqrt {1-x^2}}= Ce^t$$

Where C is an arbitrary constant.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Bernoulli-type equation. Set $u=x^{-2}$ to find
$$
\dot u = -2x^{-3}\dot x = -2u+2
$$ 
to get a linear order one equation that can be solved via the usual means.